# Save image through curl from url to local folder

Tags: php, image, curl, save

Hi i want to save the **image** from a web **url** to my **local** folder .below is my code

```
<?php
$url = 'http://dev.aviesta.com.mx/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/r/bridal-shoes1.jpg';
$saveto = '/var/www/';
  function grab_image($url,$saveto){
      $url = 'http://dev.aviesta.com.mx/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/r/bridal-shoes1.jpg';
      $saveto = '/var/www/';
      $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
   }

?>
```

i have try this code but it doesn't work for me please suggest me some idea

Comment: copy('http://short-and-sweet.com/method.png', '/var/www/keep-fopen/enabled.png');

Comment: Did you find an answer that works?

Comment: here is the full code which works fine 
<?php
//Get the file
$content = 'http://dev.aviesta.com.mx/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/r/bridal-shoes1.jpg ';
$content1 = explode('/', $content);
$end = end($content1);
echo $end;
//print_r($content1[12]);
//Store in the filesystem.
$my_file = $end;
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); //implicitly creates file
$path = '/var/www/'.$end;
chmod($path, 0777); 
copy($content, $path);

 ?>

Answer (score 1):

Why use cURL?

```
$url = 'http://dev.aviesta.com.mx/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/r/bridal-shoes1.jpg';
$saveto = '/var/www/image_' . time() . '.jpg';

grab_image($url, $saveto);

function grab_image($url, $saveto) {

  // Assumes a correctly encoded URL
  $image = file_get_contents($url);
  if (!$image)
    return false;

  file_put_contents($saveto, $image); 
  if (!file_exists($saveto))
    return false;

  return true;
}
```

Also be sure to check that the web server has permission to write to /var/www/

Answer (score 1):

in **php.ini** file made one change as below

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

and uncomment following line.

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

### OR

```
$img = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$response['user_id'].'/picture?type=large');
$image_name = time().".jpg";
/* putting image into the orignal images folder to keep the original image */
$upload_path = "img".DS."origional_images".DS."";
file_put_contents("img".DS."origional_images".DS.$image_name, $img);
```

#### tried code

i have tried below code according to the comment you have posted.
unfortunatly in your comment you have extra ' at the end of url link get rid of that extra ' and it will work as expected.

```
$img = file_get_contents('http://dev.aviesta.com.mx/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/r/bridal-shoes1.jpg');
$image_name = time().".jpg";

$upload_path = "img/";
file_put_contents("img/".$image_name, $img);
```

Comment: <?php
//Get the file
$content = file_get_contents('http://dev.aviesta.com.mx/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/r/bridal-shoes1.jpg');
//Store in the filesystem.
 $fp = fopen('/var/www/ajaxForm/loading.gif', 'w'); 
 fwrite($fp, $content);
  fclose($fp);
   ?>

i got the folowing eroor

Comment: its because may be you have ' at the end of file_get_contents... just click link you have given in your comment i bet u will see 404

Comment: @DipeshParmar, given that Rohit is saving to `/var/www/image` implies he is using a Linux or Mac stack, why would he need to uncomment a Windows dll in php.ini?

Comment: In order to use extra library u need to enable it before use it...just like function.....to call any function u MUST DECLARE FUNCTION FIRST.

Comment: @DipeshParmar dll files are used exclusively by windows, PHP extensions have a `.so` extension in Linux/Mac

Comment: @PassKit thanx i didn't know it. i never used linux before...thanx learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$fp = fopen($saveto, 'wb');`.

Comment: please elaborate your answer a bit , i have a confusion how to use your answer